# NHibernate clearing associations - wrong query generated

Tags: c#, multithreading, hibernate, nhibernate

Suppose I have following models:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I have them joined by many-to-many relationship so when I do something like:

```
user.Roles.Remove(role);
Session.Save(user);
```

NHibernate will generate query:

```
DELETE FROM User_Role WHERE UserId = @p1 AND RoleId = @p2
```

which is fine, except for when `role` is last item in `Roles` collection. Then the query will look like this:

```
DELETE FROM User_Role WHERE UserId = @p1
```

so no checking for RoleId this time, just deleting whone collection. Which is wrong! I have many threads working on same data and this second query causes me to lose associations. Suppose we have user with single role loaded by 2 threads at the same time. One adds new role and saves this first, now the second thread removes role. Then trying to `Save` will cause it to delete not single association but also second one just created by other thread.

So the question is: how to force NH to always use this first query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating code of NHibernate I came to conclusion that there is no way to change this.